# How does covering ally works in Final Fantasy Brave Exvius?

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

I have a team of Ramza, Elza, Cecil, ExDeath, Minfilia.

For some reason, during my fight with Titan (the Raid Boss), Cecil would 90% of the time cover Ramza instead of Minfilia or ExDeath whose defense and HP are lower than Ramza. Why is this? How to make Cecil cover ExDeath or Minfilia instead of Ramza?

**Ramza**

Lv 100

HP 4343

**Elza**

Lv 100

HP 5122

**Cecil**

Lv 100

HP 4552

**ExDeath**

Lv 100

HP 3513

**Minfilia**

Lv 59~

HP 2929

Tell me if more information are needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the wiki http://exvius.gamepedia.com/Cover

> When more than 1 unit are attacked at the same time, the chance to
>   protect party member is based on the order of the party, with
>   left-most unit having the highest chance.

Cover only blocks physical attacks, but if you enhance Golem to have provoke, you could make it more likely for the enemy to attack your tank and can still use cover if needed.

Edit: in case you aren't sure, left-most refers to before you go into battle. That person will be your top left character, but if that's your tank, he's more likely to cover the person below him (second from left).